# Can I efficiently fork a ramfs partition?

Tags: memory, ram, fork, tmpfs

I want a ramfs (or equivalent, but strictly RAM only) partition which will serve as a read-only master instance from which any number of identical children can be forked.

When a process forks, this is very efficient because the pages are copy-on-write. Can I get a similarly efficient fork/clone of a ramfs partition?

Comment: Interesting idea: the file-system would have to reside in RAM owned by a process. It would be interesting to know if it can be done, as it may have other uses. However from a practical point of view, use a union file-system.

Comment: Would a union filesystem allow the fork to modify and delete files without affecting the original?

Comment: Unionfs is used to layer a writeable fs on one or more readonly fs. Check out the simpler [overlayfs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Overlay_filesystem).

Comment: @spraff yes. It uses a read-only base. Then adds a writtable layer. You can have one for each branch. It does not work like COW. But will have the same effect.